# Regarding Hinsberg reagent, potassium salt of primary amine soluble in base become insoluble after acidification?

Tags: organic-chemistry, amines, salt, reagents

> Distinguish between ethylamine, diethylamine and triethylamine by using Hinsberg's reagent?
> Ans. This reaction is useful for the distinction of primary, secondary and tertiary amines.
> (i) Primary amine (like ethyl amine) is treated with Hinsberg's reagent (benzene sulphonyl chloride) forms N-alkyl benzene sulphonamide which dissolve in aqueous KOH solution to form a clear solution of potassium salt and upon acidification gives insoluble N-alkyl benzene sulphonamide.

[image]

> (ii) Secondary amine like diethyl amine is treated with benzene sulphonyl chloride forms N,N-diethyl benzene which sulphonyl amide remains insoluble in aqueous KOH and does not dissolve in acid.

So as given in the reaction, when we react N-Ethyl benzene sulphonamide with KOH it form a potassium salt. When the potassium salt is acidified, why is the N-alkyl benzene sulphonamide insoluble when it was earlier soluble?

Comment: In what solvent?

Comment: Potassium hydroxide solution, presumably

Comment: Please substitute images with typed text. You might keep relevant images of structures but at least add typed text.

Comment: Why would you expect an organic compound like N-ethyl benzenesulfonamide to be aqueous soluble? The potassium salt is soluble because it is an ionic species, the neutral compound will not be.

Comment: @Waylander For the record the schematic reports that the K-salt is insoluble. That might be the source of the confusion.